# Random number based on input string

Tags: php, unique

Am I possible to make unique number (code / string / short hash) based on input string?

I need to get short unique number for each unique string (without comparing existing values)

Comment: $uniquestring = uniqid($string);

Comment: That is the best I can suggest without any code to reference

Comment: uniqid works fine, but it will concat **string + unique_number**. Would be that number still unique if I will delete string from the result?

Comment: if nobody posts anymore comments and/or answers (within the next 5-10 mins), then that will mean that either your question is too broad, or unclear. The good people need an example of what you want.

Comment: and my 5 minutes to you have elapsed. Good luck with that, enjoy.

Comment: @Lucfia yes, it will still be unique, you have declared a new variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but if I understand correctly you could use a hash i.e. `$code = md5($val1 . $val2 . $val3);` OR a unique id `$code = uniqid($val1 . $val2 . $val3);`

Comment: `md5($val1 . $val2 . $val3)` produces less unique values than simply `$val1 . $val2 . $val3`.